# Jenkins/Hudson parameter usage

Tags: java, jenkins

I have a question, if it is possible to define a String parameter and use it in url repository? It always writes red that the repository does not exist, when I use a parameter like this ${NAME}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are fully allowed to do that. In fact, I do this every day, where my branch builds append the branch number (from a dropdown parameter) to the URL

`http://svn.repo.com/some_project/branch/${NAME}` is a valid SVN Repo URL

To avoid the red warning message, do the following:

- Go to **Manage Jenkins** (configure)
- Scroll down until you see **Subversion** section
- Check mark **Validate repository URLs to the first variable name**
- Click **Save**

Just one note on polling. The SVN polling will use the last full (with the expanded variable) URL that was run. In other words, it will remember your ${NAME} parameter for polling, until you run the job with a different value for {NAME}

Comment: Thanks for the extra information to avoid the red warning!  That's what I couldn't find anywhere else.